# SWRevealViewController causes infinite loop initializing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I've been using SWRevealViewController library for a long time without problems, I really like it!
This time I've had to add it to a project so this is what I've done:

- I've taken the "RevealControllerExample" sample.
- I've copied directly SWRevealViewController.h/.m to my project.
- I've copied directly FrontViewController.h/.m/.xib to my project I've copied directly RearViewController.h/.m/.xib to my project but I removed all code inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath (I didn't need it for the moment).
- I've ignored the RightViewController because I didn't need it.
- I've added to my AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions all the initialization code except the one for the RightViewController because I don't need it.

This is how I have the initialization code:

```
    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
    revealController.delegate = self;


    self.swViewController = revealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.swViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

And when I launch the app this crashes because an infinite loop. This is the call stack:

```
...(here comes inifite calls to transitionFromViewController)...
#36603 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36604 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36605 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36606 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36607 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36608 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36609 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36610 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36611 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36612 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36613 0x00118620 in __80-[SWRevealViewController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:inView:]_block_invoke_2 at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1683
#36614 0x0011759c in __82-[SWRevealViewController _performTransitionOperation:withViewController:animated:]_block_invoke at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1470
#36615 0x0011757e in -[SWRevealViewController _performTransitionOperation:withViewController:animated:] at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:1497
#36616 0x001137be in -[SWRevealViewController initWithRearViewController:frontViewController:] at /path/to/myproject/SWRevealViewController.m:635
#36617 0x000e1ec0 in -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] at /path/to/myproject/AppDelegate.m:35
```

I've tested the sample directly and of course it works.
I'm using Xcode 8 and I'm compiling with iOS 10.1.
The only "different" thing I'm doing is that my app is landscape only, and I don't know if this affects the side menu.

What could it be happening?

Comment: you need to integrate `SWRevealViewController` with your project and needs only left side navigation ?

Comment: Yes, that is. I need a Left side navigation. I've used this library several times for this same purpose with no problem, but this time I don't know what it's happening.

Comment: actually i have done this several times using storyboard haven't coded like you do in `appdeleate`, i can post a solution to you step by step if you opt.

Comment: I would really appreciate that. I could try with your code.

Comment: Wonton check my ans and let me know your feedback, apologies for late ans :)

Comment: Thanks vaibhav! As soon as I can I will try your solution and I let you know how it was. I'm not using Storyboard but ViewControllers directly, I hope I can adapt your solution.

Comment: that i have already intimate you regarding using storyboard's in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is now little bit changes in code using [`SWRevealViewController` library](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) for left side swipe menu, here are some tricky steps to follow in order to use correctly.

Class configuration:

1. Add few classes inside your project and its storyboard as well [download link](https://github.com/appcoda/Slideout-Sidebar-Demo):

   - `SWRevealViewController.h`
   - `SWRevealViewController.m`
   - `SidebarViewController.h`
   - `SidebarViewController.m`
2. In order to create front view and rare view please see storyboard configuration.
3. To add some more `viewControllers` inside menu, first you need to create cocoa classes and add the following code.

   - inside .h file create IBOutlet of side button which is used for navigate later.
   - import `"SWRevealViewController.h"`

     ```
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
     ```
   - Inside .m file add the following code inside `viewDidLoad` method:

     ```
     // Change button color
     _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:0.9f];

     // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
     _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
     _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

     // Set the gesture
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
     ```

Stroyboard configuration:

1. In order to make a front view `viewController`

   - Connect any of the `vc` from `Reveal View Controller` using segue and choose `reveal view controller` see inside image:

     [image]
   - Then must set the identifier of the above seugue as `sw_front` see image:
     [image]
2. To configure other `viewController` as menu you must have to connect them from `Sidebar scene` `vc's` cell using segue without identifier like first image.
3. Connect all the `sidebarButton` `IBOutlet` before tap.
4. To add some more viewController you need to add cell inside `Sidebar scene` vc and make some changes inside `menuItems` array found in `SidebarViewController.m` class but do not forgot to make that cell identifire same as menuItmes.

   ```
   menuItems = @[@"title", @"news", @"comments", @"map", @"calendar", @"wishlist", @"bookmark", @"tag", @"anotherVc_1", @"anotherVc_2"];
   ```

Note: You can remove `prepareForSegue` methods from `SidebarViewController.m` class and make separate vc for all the cells for transition, `prepareForSegue` methods handling segue transmission which is redirecting a user so same vc with diff appearance.

Hope this helps you a lot.

Comment: Thanks vaibhav! I've keep having problems with this solution, maybe because I haven't been able to adapt this solution properly from storyboards to ViewControllers. I've finally decided to use another side menu library and its working now (this library is LGSideMenuController). Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: actually migrating to another solution is a good practice, anyway its your choice and affords thanks for you feedback.